Problem with ECL recognizing a Python class through Python embedding
So, I basically wanted to make use of PyTorch on ECL, through python embedding.When we constructed the architecture of a simple model by creating a class as shown below, we observed a few unusual errors like the class name not being defined:
f() := EMBED(PY)

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class model_1(nn.Module):
    def _init_(self):
        super(model_1, self)._init_()
        input_size = torch.randint(10, 100, (1,)).item()
        hidden_size = torch.randint(10, 100, (1,)).item()
        output_size = torch.randint(2, 10, (1,)).item()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x


model = model_1()


batch_size = 32
input_size = model.layer1.in_features
input_data = torch.randn(batch_size, input_size)


target = torch.randint(0, model.layer2.out_features, (batch_size,))


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    output = model(input_data)
    

    loss = criterion(output, target)
    
 
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')
    

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()


ENDEMBED;
f();

We were getting the following error:
Error: 0: pyembed: name 'model_1' is not defined

We also tried to run the above model without classes just by using functions, and this is what we are getting:
f() := EMBED(PY)
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

def create_model():
    input_size = torch.randint(10, 100, (1,)).item()
    hidden_size = torch.randint(10, 100, (1,)).item()
    output_size = torch.randint(2, 10, (1,)).item()
   
    layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
    activation = nn.ReLU()
    layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
    softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
    
    def forward(x):

        x = layer1(x)
        x = activation(x)
        x = layer2(x)
        x = softmax(x)
        return x
    
    
    parameters = list(layer1.parameters()) + list(layer2.parameters())
    
    return forward, parameters


model, parameters = create_model()

batch_size = 32
input_size = parameters[0].size(1)  # Input size of the first layer

input_data = torch.randn(batch_size, input_size)

target = torch.randint(0, parameters[-1].size(0), (batch_size,))  

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = optim.SGD(parameters, lr=0.01)

num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    output = model(input_data)
    
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

ENDEMBED;

f();

On running this, we were getting the following error (Although torch is already configured, I ran an import torch in a simple python program, didn't give me an error):
Error: 0: pyembed: name 'torch' is not defined

How can I create an object of the mentioned class above using python embedding?

You need to have a common global area shared between calls.  Your class definition is out of scope when you are trying to use it.  You also need to define a persist setting.  It’s all in the following blog:
Advanced Python Embedding
Here is another blog you may find helpful:
Power Macros in Python
Thanks for your question!
